# Selecting index in SWT table

Tags: java, checkbox, swt

I have this code which prints the data from the column in the table but how can i get the value of another columns ( I have 3 columns) but it only prints the 1st column?

This is my code:

```
Table table = (Table) e.widget;
            if( e.detail == SWT.CHECK ) {
                System.out.println(e.item);
                if( table.indexOf( ( TableItem )e.item ) == table.getSelectionIndex() ) {
                    TableItem ti = ( TableItem )e.item;
                    ti.setChecked( !ti.getChecked() );
                }

            } else {
                TableItem ti = ( TableItem )e.item;
                ti.setChecked( !ti.getChecked() );
            }
```

Output:

```
TableItem {MIC0012345}
```

Expected Output:

```
TableItem {MIC0012345, 2012, 2000} //(where 2012 and 2000 are remaining columns)
```

PS: i got the code here from stackoverflow

Comment: Where is the code which _prints data from the column_ that you mention? The posted code is about manipulating the checked state.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the text of a table item, use `TableItem::getText()`. In a multi-column table, use `TableItem::getText(int)`. The index parameter is zero-based and denotes the column of which the text should be retrieved. Note that columns are indexed in creation order, re-ordering the columns later does not affect this method.

Comment: what exactly have you tried? And what is not working? Edit the question to Post your code and Tell what is the expected and the actual outcome.

Comment: It wants me to upgrade into JRE 1.8 so that it can work and when i tried what you said.

Comment: @abrakadabarahastags Use `ti.getText(0)` etc. Don't actually use `TableItem::getText(0)`.